# Issue getting value of element

Tags: javascript

I am facing a perplexing problem.

I have an HTML element that looks like this:

```
<tr id = "pracarea6196" value = "success" name = "pracarea" class = "success">
```

Whenever I try to get the value of the element, I get undefined:

```
document.getElementById("pracarea6196").value
```

Why would that be the case?

Comment: Does `.getAttribute("value")` work?

Comment: yes.  weird.  any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Value is not a valid attribute for the HTMLTableRowElement interface so you have to use it by getAttribute and setAttribute.

Comment: Its not supposed to work. Youre supposed to used it with things like inputs and buttons.

Comment: If you need to add custom attributes, and values, to an element please consider the `data-*`-prefixed attributes; that way it'll validate under HTML 5. Though there's nothing (save the love of all things good, and beautiful, in the world) stopping you from explicitly setting a `value` property to a `<tr>` element (`trElement.value = trElement.getAttribute('value')`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr` tags do not have a value. `input` tags do. Therefore, the DOM API treats this like any other attribute.

```
document.getElementById('pracarea6196').getAttribute('value')
```